# Android fragment static method not displaying listview items

Tags: android, listview, android-fragments

I have posted that question previously..but did not get any suggestion thats Why I am posting it Again..I have fragment to display itms in listview..So, I have(part of my code):

```
public class TwoFragment extends Fragment  {

    Button btn1;
    static ListView listview;
    ProgressDialog mProgressDialog;
    static Activity activity;

    public TwoFragment() {

    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_two2, container, false);
         activity = getActivity();
        listview = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.listview);
        return view;
    }

    public static void display(final String serverResponse) {

        @SuppressWarnings("unused")
        final class DownloadJSON extends AsyncTask<String, String, Void> {
            private  JSONObject jsonobject;
            private  JSONArray jsonarray;
                private  ListViewAdapter adapter;
            private  ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> arraylist;
            @Override
            protected Void doInBackground(String... params) {
                try {

                    jsonarray = new JSONArray(serverResponse);
                    Gson gson = new Gson();

                    User[] user = gson.fromJson(jsonarray.toString(), User[].class);
                    for (int i = 0; i < user.length; i++) {
                        HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
                        map.put("name", user[i].getFullname());
                        arraylist.add(map);

                    }

                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    Log.e("Error", e.getMessage());
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                return null;
            }

            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(Void args) {

                adapter = new ListViewAdapter(activity, arraylist);
                listview.setAdapter(adapter);
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

In this code I am not getting any display inside listview..

Comment: put your adapter code and from where you call this method.?

Comment: where you have called "display" method??

Comment: I am using tablayout..so.display method will call automatically from mainActivity..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're holding a static reference to the Activity and the ListView? Thats the prime example of [an memory leak](http://android-developers.blogspot.de/2009/01/avoiding-memory-leaks.html).

Remove the static keyword from the display method and also from the activity and listview variables. Actually you don't need a reference to the Activity since you can get the instance with 'getActivity' in the 'onPostExecute'. But only if the fragment is still attached to the Activity.

**Also you are defining the AsyncTask, but not calling it with [instance].execute();**

Now that I look at the code, does it even compile? As far as I know defining classes in a method is not allowed.

Comment: I can not remove static keyword from display() method.Actually this method will call after button pressed..That code i have not posted..

Comment: Does the MainAcitvity set up the Fragment? If it does, then it should be able to reference the instance of it and therefore able to call the method even if its not static.

Comment: From logcat I found that,the only problem is in onPostExecute() method..with adapter = new ListViewAdapter(activity, arraylist);
                listview.setAdapter(adapter); this two lines..

Comment: Well, what does logcat say? Illegal UI access from background thread?

Comment: java.lang.NullPointerException onPostExecute(TwoFragment.java: 137),onPostExecute(TwoFragment.java: 1)
....i.e     adapter = new ListViewAdapter(activity, arraylist);
                listview.setAdapter(adapter);

Comment: onPostExecute? I would expect it to crash in doInBackground since arraylist is not initialized. Well, NPEs are easy to debug. Place a few breakpoints and fire up the debugger. Come back if it still does not work.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/113492/discussion-between-preeti-and-gpuschka).